# Voltage reference vs voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, biasing

I need to bias some op amp inputs with a voltage. I’m in the 10-60 hz range. I need the bias voltage to be as low noise as possible, like -155 dbv . Would a voltage reference, voltage regulator, or even zener diode work the best here?  I’m confused as to which part would work the best. And do I need to drive the bias through a voltage buffer or can I put it right onto the inputs?

Comment: How stable must this be, as temperature changes?

Comment: "as good as possible"  how much liquid helium can you afford?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221312/voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-reference ?

Answer (score 1):

A voltage regulator is meant to keep voltage consistant across widely varying output current. A voltage reference keeps it consistant across a range of other conditions but is meant to operate without a load on it. You want a voltage reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal of -155dBv, given -160dBv is 10^-8 below 1volt (peak-peak?) is 10 nanoVolts.

We know, using Vnoise = sqrt(K * T /C)

that 10 picoFarads as the Cap, in a low-pass-filter with **any** value of R, will produce 20 microVolts RMS total integrated noise.

You want to be 2,000X lower noise than 10pF will produce.

Thus your capacitor must be 10pF * ( 2,000 * 2,000) = 40 uFarad. Try a 47uF.

Pick your R as you wish. Just use at least 40uF in the LPF.

==================

The OP wants at least -155, which is close to -154, which is 6dB more voltage than the 40uF produces. 6dB, or 2x more voltage, allows 4x small cap, at 10uF.

Comment: How about thinfilm cap?

Comment: That's a neat trick with the capacitor value, presumably it involves the resistor having a defined noise_power/rtHz regardless of R. I've not seen a derivation of that result anywhere. Is there a published derivation you could link to?

Comment: I was exploring the relationship of R and C and the total integrated  random thermal (resistor) noise, and attempting to come up with a nomograph to summarize. A very experienced Aps Engr looked briefly at my efforts, and advised "That is just the total noise of a sampled-capacitor," and YES he was right. @Neal_UK: have not found one yet.

Comment: This is the ideal noise case for a thin film resistor, but a Zener or any voltage ref diode may be worse so you choose an ultra low noise Vref that is ultra-stable, I believe.

Comment: @ Sunnyskyguy Is the excess noise (in non-thin-film Rs) a shot-noise proportional to sqrt(current) thru the resistor?